# Заменить каждое второе двоеточие в mysql

Tags: php

Подскажите, каким образом заменить в столбце БД MYSQL каждое второе двоеточие?

Т.е. имеются записи типа:

> Скачать бесплатно:что-то:что-то

Нужно как-то пробежаться по базе и удалить каждое второе двоеточие.

Думала в сторону скрипта  - не могу придумать.
А также в сторону экспорта базы и автозамены. Но не могу найти решение по такой замене.

Comment: Количество двоеточий в записях - всегда две штуки? или ноль-один-два? или от X до Y? если последнее - то сколько максимум? И "удалить" - это вот реально удалить, получить в итоге *Скачать бесплатно:что-точто-то*?

Comment: MySQL запрос `update table set str=concat(substring_index(str,':',2),substr(str,length(substring_index(str,':',2))+2)) where str like '%:%:'` удалит глобально по всей таблице везде где в поле более 1 двоеточия. если вы конечно задачу правильно описали ...